# Using FutureBuilder in a named route with arguments

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` that represents a list of conversations(Inbox). When a user taps on a list item(conversation) we push to a named route with conversation id as argument.
On the new window we get the conversation messages(http request) using `FutureBuilder` based on the passed argument(conversation id).

Everything works great, except that when the user clicks the back button the build method is called again and a new http request is made when the window starts closing.

I know it is not recommended to create the `Future` in a build method, but what is the best approach in this case to get the passed argument as well.

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

Here is my simplified code:

```
class Messages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessagesState createState() => _MessagesState();
}

class _MessagesState extends State<Messages> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String conversationID = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print("Conv: $conversationID");
    final messages = Api.getMessages(conversationID);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Messages"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: messages,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return Center(child: Text("messages"));
            }));
  }
}
```

Here the build method is called 2 times: once when the window is open and once when is closing, making 2 http requests.

If I move the messages future outside of build method I don't have access to conversationID argument that is passed from Navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should override the method initState from your _MessageState;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final String conversationID = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final messages = Api.getMessages(conversationID);
  }
```

Also, you should declare your objects above the override, that way, the first time you get into the screen it will make the call, but the next ones it wont. Also, as you saved it in a variable, you will not need to make further calls, it will just load what it had saved

An example of code:

```
Future<dynamic> messages;
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        final String conversationID = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        final messages = Api.getMessages(conversationID);
      }
```

The rest of the code would be the same.

Hope it helped

Here is an example from a project i did:

[EDIT]The declaration of the class:

```
class mainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  String firebase_uid;
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  mainMenu({Key key, @required this.firebase_uid}) : super(key: key);
  Future<UserCompleteObject> user;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(firebase_uid);
}
```

[EDIT]... Navigating to the class:

```
Future navigateToMainMenu(context, uid) async {
  Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => mainMenu(firebase_uid: uid)));
}
```

...
    Future future_user;

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Consigue los datos iniciales de los usuarios
    future_user = get_datos_user_app(key, UUID);
  }
```

.....

```
 child: FutureBuilder<UserCompleteObject>(
            future: future_user,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

...

```
Future<UserCompleteObject> get_datos_user_app(String key, String UID) async {
```

Comment: It throws an error when I try to call conversationID = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments; in initState() : "Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter."

Comment: Ok, in my case, what i did, was to initialize the class directly with the info necessary with the class, i have updated the answer